# Oracle export/import from US7ASCII to AL32UTF8

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, database-migration

I have 2 databases
OLD: 10.2.0.4.0 US7ASCII
NEW: 11.2.0.3.0 AL32UTF8

I want to move entire schema from the OLD to the NEW, the following is my command, export is ok.

```
exp userid=username/password@database owner=*** file=d:\export.dmp
```

But import has error

```
imp userid=username/password@database fromuser=*** touser=***  file=d:\export.dmp

IMP-00067: Could not convert to server character set's handle
IMP-00000: Import terminated unsuccessfully
```

Is there any suggestion for this issue? Because the database has BLOB field and I cannot export SQL command and INSERT it into the new database.

Answer (score 0):

UAL32UTF8 is a superset of US7ASCII, so  you should be able to import correctly. Have you set correctly your NLS_PARAMETERS ?
I suggest also, if you can, to use Datapump instead of the deprecacted imp/exp tools.

Comment: I found some documents said about NLS_PARAMETERS, but I cannot find how to assign NLS_PARAMETERS in exp/imp command. And Datapump seems to need DBA privilege ?

Comment: The variable NLS_LANG can be set in your environment.